# Hiding the parent component when displaying child component

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple post titles and when I click on individual post title details of that individual post are displayed. I want to hide the parent component on
clicking child component(list of post titles here).

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Posts from './Posts';
    import Post from './Post';
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/'  element={<Posts></Posts>}>
    <Route path=':id'  element={<Post></Post>}></Route>
    </Route>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
    );

    reportWebVitals();`
```

I want to hide the "/" path component when i navigate to Post component.

I am able to do this when i put these two routes as siblings but unable when i make a parent child           relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you have nested the single post Route in the "posts" Route, so it will work as a Layout, whatever is in the layout will be always displayed.
i suggest you do this:

```
<Routes>
<Route path='/'  element={<PostsLayout/>}>
    <Route index  element={<Posts/>}/>
    <Route path=':id'  element={<Post/>}/>
</Route>
</Routes>
```

and don't forget to include `<Outlet />` in your PostsLayout